# Problems with VBA VARIANT return type and 64-bit build of C++ Excel add-in

Tags: c++, vba, excel, 64-bit

In the process of migrating our C++ Excel add-in from a 32-bit to 64-bit build I've noticed some odd behaviour with functions that return a VARIANT data type.

For example, we might typically have a declaration like this in the addin VBA wrapper declaring the entry point into the XLL:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function Foo Lib "addin.xll" Alias "xlFoo" () As Variant
```

and then in the C++ source for the XLL we would have something like this:

```
VARIANT __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall xlFoo()
{
  int result = calc_foo_int();

  VARIANT ret;
  VariantInit(&ret);
  V_VT(&ret) = VT_I4;
  V_I4(&ret) = result;

  return ret;
}
```

Now, in the 32-bit world, everything works just fine. We can call this function in a VBA script or in an Excel sheet cell and we will get back the result we were expecting every time.

In the 64-bit world, however, things aren't so great. We can actually call this function just fine inside a VBA script and it will behave normally, but if we try calling it directly from an Excel cell entry, i.e. by typing:

```
=Foo()
```

**Excel crashes and asks to restart!**

I have searched high and low, but I can't find anything anywhere stating that there is any special other way of handling VARIANT return types in 64-bit Excel or that this is somehow problematic and should be avoided (despite being fine in the 32-bit world).

The closest thing I've seen described is in this article, which seems to imply (oddly) that VARIANT return types are not supported in 64-bit Office callback functions:

[You must declare the return type explicitly in a VBA macro that you run in a 64-bit environment](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2210978)

So my best hunch is that maybe for the same reason VARIANT return types are not supported by 64-bit Excel addins either, at least as far as being able to be called from cells within a spreadsheet?

Is anyone able to confirm or deny that this is the case or perhaps shed some further light on the issue?

Any and all help gratefully received!

*(oh, I should probably point out that I realise using a VARIANT return type for a simple integer value in the case above is overkill - it's just meant to be a simple demonstration case - some of our return types are complex arrays of mixed data types and do warrant a VARIANT return type)*

Comment: What happens if you wrap it in another function?

Comment: Wrapped inside VBA the call is fine - it's just the naked call from an Excel cell that causes the issue. We also have functions used solely in Excel cells that use the XLOPER12 interface too and they are also all fine. My main concern is that if anyone ever types in a call to a VARIANT returning function in Excel, then the session will immediately crash - which is less than ideal ;-)

Comment: I mean if you call your function something other than `Foo()` (let's say `Bar` and then create a UDF that can be called from the worksheet called Foo which just uses `Foo = Bar()` so the user is actually calling a UDF from the worksheet that is inside a VBA module, but that UDF is returning your function instead. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure. It does, thanks. And it works. But if the user ever types =Bar() the entire Excel session will crash. Note that Excel will try to help the user too, so as soon as they start typing "=B..." it will start to suggest "=Bar()", so this can happen easily.

Comment: Even if you declare Bar with a private scope? :)

Comment: Hmm... yes, that's interesting. I could try that. The VBA entry points are defined to be used generically through different sheets VBA scripts, so there will need to be a public interface, but I suppose we could generate the addin entry point declarations as private and then a public wrapper in VBA for each one of these that is public. Not very pretty and more overhead, but I guess it might work. Will take a look into this. Thanks.

Comment: If you just place `Public Function Foo() As Variant` etc in the same module as `Private Declare PtrSafe Function Bar()` etc... then you shouldn't have to re-factor anything - if it's all in the same workbook it will just pick up the public UDF instead.